# Building nav from <h3>: can't create <li> around <a> in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery, but I've got this far:

```
$('div.team_text').each(function() {
     $('<a>', {
          "href" : $(this).attr("id"),
          "text" : $(this).find("h3").text()
   }).appendTo('ul.tabs');
});
```

This gives me the links as I need them from the `div`s that contain the people's names as `<h3>`s:

```
 <a href="teamBod2">Person Name</a>
```

But what I need to generate is:

```
<li><a href="teamBod2">Person Name</a></li>
```

How do I change my jQuery?

Comment: What HTML are you *starting* with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap)

```
}).wrap("<li/>").parent().appendTo('ul.tabs');
```

Note the call to `parent` after `wrap`, because `wrap` returns the original jQuery object (in your case, the link), but what we want to do is append the `li` (with its freshly-wrapped link) to the list.

Comment: you could either add a `.parent` before `.appendTo` or cache in a var and use `wrap`. +1 for using wrap though.

Comment: `.wrap(..).parent().appendTo(..`

Comment: Trying to read the API and keep up with the comments at the same time, challenging.

Comment: As a sidenote, doing the wrapping and appending outside the loop would be more efficient, depending on how many elements there are ?

Answer (score 0):

tymeJV seems to have captured it pretty well. Just a couple of changes suggested based on caching selectors and updating the DOM.

```
var $h = $("<div>");//create a holder for the new elements

$('div.team_text').each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);//cache 'this'
     $h.append(
     $('<a>').attr({//I use the attr method to add the properties, I think that it is easier to read.
          "href" : $this.attr("id"),
          "text" : $this.find("h3").text()
        }).wrap("<li>")
        );
});

$('ul.tabs').append($h.children());
```

If there is no value added with this answer, I will delete it!